# Wordpress caching error, "Cache key cannot be empty"

Tags: php, wordpress

Windows Server 2016, IIS 10, PHP 8.0

When I try to access the admin section of my website - I inherited this site and restored it from a backup, so I don't know what the state was prior to me getting it - with debugging turned on, I get

`PHP Notice: Function WP_Object_Cache::add was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Cache key must not be an empty string. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 6.1.0.) in D:\inetpub\sites\buyacarlease,com\wp-includes\functions.php on line 5865`

The file and line number just points to the line that displays the error. It doesn't help.

I checked for cache plugins. There aren't any.

I renamed the plugins folder. No change.

I read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_object_cache/. No help there.

I searched the database for any options entries called 'cache.' There are two, and they have values, and don't appear to be related in any case.

I renamed the theme. No change.

I google'd "cache key." Nothing.

I searched stackoverflow for 'wordpress cache key'. Nothing.

I cleared cache and cookies on my browser. No change.

I added the line

`define("ENABLE_CACHE", false);`

to wp-config.php. No change.

There is no "cache" directory under wp-content.

I'm at a loss. What do I do?

Comment: For these kinds of errors you sometimes have to hack core temporarily. Go to the line that is showing the message and add [`debug_print_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) right before it. This will usually show the actual offending function call.

Comment: Problem is it's not a PHP error, it's a mechanical error in the code, meaning it's an if/then statement; if false, then execute function_that_looks_like_an_error. I can backtrace because it's just following Wordpress functions, easy enough. If I try to default the if/then to true, things that come later don't work.

Comment: It isn't a PHP error, true. But you just need to go to the file that holds that class, and into the `add()` method. Hack that by adding at the top `if(!$key){debug_print_backtrace();}`. That should hopefully help you find the culprit.